# Heroku page rendered, but internal server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

this is from hartl sample_app. pushed up at the end of chapter 4. 
precompiled assets. no db created, but did db migrate and push anyway.
page is rendered, but still internal server error. error message on page is
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.
any ideas?

```
2011-10-19T16:29:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pages/about" for 110.159.158.86 at 2011-10-19 09:29:50 -0700
2011-10-19T16:29:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by PagesController#about as HTML
2011-10-19T16:29:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered pages/about.html.erb within layouts/application (14.7ms)
2011-10-19T16:29:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 85ms
2011-10-19T16:29:50+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 110.159.158.86 - - [19/Oct/2011:09:29:50 -0700] "GET /pages/about HTTP/1.1" 500 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1" floating-summer-4928.heroku.com
2011-10-19T16:29:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-10-19T16:29:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3403352161580950105_25993880'
2011-10-19T16:29:50+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-10-19T16:29:50+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

I've destroyed that app an created a new one. there doesn't seem to be any visible errors in the logs, but the page is still not showing

```
2011-10-19T17:12:32+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 110.159.158.86 - - [19/Oct/2011:10:12:32 -0700] "GET /pages/about HTTP/1.1" 500 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1" vivid-snow-8105.heroku.com
2011-10-19T17:23:25+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/rails.png] stale, valid, store
2011-10-19T17:23:36+00:00 heroku[router]: GET vivid-snow-8105.heroku.com/pages/about dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=12ms status=500 bytes=728
2011-10-19T17:23:36+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /pages/about] miss
```

Answer (score 1):

the solution was to change config.assets.compile to true in config/environments/production.rb. it took me a long time to find this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the errors in development?

Have you tried the extended logging add-ons, or Airbrake to try and see what the error might be?

From what I can see floating-summer-4928.heroku.com is no longer a valid Heroku app.

Comment: I've destroyed that app an created a new one. there doesn't seem to be any visible errors in the logs, but the page is still not showing

Comment: I've destroyed that app an created a new one. vivid-snow-8105.heroku.com

Comment: no errors in development. i've added extended logging, but now the logs are completely empty

Answer (score 0):

From your reference to 'precompiled assets' and I can see 'assets' in your log it looks like your using Rails 3.1? And from your URLs of your apps your using a bamboo stack - I think that if you try using the new cedar stack (heroku create --stack cedar) you will find things work for you.